# Finding real and imaginary parts of $ -i \ln(1\pm \sqrt{2})+{\frac{\pi}{2}}+2\pi k$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have found an expression for $\arcsin(i)$ as a complex number $z$. It is
$$
z = -i \ln(1\pm \sqrt{2})+{\frac{\pi}{2}}+2\pi k
$$
How should I find the real and imaginary parts of $\arcsin(i)$ from here?

Answer (score 2):

The real part is anything without a coefficient of $i$, and the imaginary part is anything *with* a coefficient of $i$. Note that for the imaginary part, you basically get rid of the $i$.

Some examples:

- Let $z = a+bi, a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $Re(z) = a, Im(z) = b$.
- Let $z = 3 + \sqrt{3} + i\sqrt2$. Then $Re(z) = 3 +\sqrt{3}, Im(z) = \sqrt2$.
- Let $z = e^{it}$, for $t \in [0,2\pi]$. Since $e^{it} = \cos(t) + i \sin(t)$, and for the $t$ given the $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$ functions are real-valued, then $Re(z) = \cos(t)$ and $Im(z) = \sin(t)$.

Anecdotally, you might want to note that your $k$'s in your answer are integers. Just a small nitpick.

Comment: I know what are real and imaginary parts, but if I go with that knowledge, then I'll have $\Re (z)={\frac{\pi}{2}}+2\pi k, \Im (z)=ln (1\pm \sqrt{2})$. But that's not correct.

Comment: The $\ln()$ function would be negative. If that's still not correct, that suggests your calculations leading up to your calculation of $z$ are not correct.

Comment: That's correct actually. The answer in book is $\Re (z)={\frac{\pi}{2}}+2\pi k-i\ln ({\sqrt{2}}+1), \Im (z)=-{\frac{\pi}{2}}+2\pi k-i\ln ({\sqrt{2}}-1)$